# Usage of PortalDelegateServlet in Liferay

Tags: servlets, delegates, liferay, portal

I'm trying to create a servlet which shares liferay session contents with my application.So I need to use `PortalDelegateServlet`.But I can not find in how to import this library to my project.I can not find any .jar files or something.

How can I import liferay java library to my project?

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases

Comment: I already downloaded  and installed Liferay with Tomcat Bundle.But i can not find PortalDelegateServlet.What is your advice?

Answer (score 2):

`PortalDelegateServlet` is in `portal-service.jar` which is a *required* part of the Liferay container.  If you grabbed a bundle (which in comment you mention the Tomcat bundle), then it is provided for you.  All you should need to do is configure your `web.xml`:

```
  <servlet>
    <!-- http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LEP-2297 -->
    <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example.MyServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

[This Liferay issue](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LEP-2297) (which is linked to in the source for [PortalDelegateServlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/PortalDelegateServlet.java)) makes it sound as if this has been available since version `4.3.0`